# download multiple duplicate files while being numbered using curl

Tags: curl

I need to download multiple of the same files under a different name is this possible with curl?

example

same picture needs to be downloaded 3 times under the name
file1
file2
file3

i have tried googling but there are no results that work for me

Answer (score 0):

Sure?

```
curl https://example.com/image.jpg -o file1 \
https://example.com/image.jpg -o file2 \
https://example.com/image.jpg -o file3
```

You can even add `-Z` if you rather want them downloaded in parallel...

This said, it is completely unnecessary and you're way better off making copies of the file after a *single* download.

Comment: I know that OP asked about curl specifically but it doesn't much make sense to connect to the same server 3 times in a row to download the same file

Comment: unless the file changes over time...